# what will be the result of ltrim or rtrim on whitespace string

Tags: sql, t-sql

Example:

```
 SELECT 'A' + ltrim('    ') + 'B'  --or SELECT 'A' + rtrim('    ') + 'B'
```

Output:

```
AB
```

So what will be the actual character after trim a whitespace string? Based on the document, the result type will either be `varchar` or `nvarchar`, so it cannot be `NULL`, and of course if it is `NULL`, it will not output `AB`. As there is nothing between `A` and `B`, it is not neither whitespace and `NULL`, what is the actual output, or what is the corresponding `varchar` or `nvarchar` for that missing character? Any ASCII reflects that?

**UPDATE:**

After run this:

```
select ASCII(rtrim('    '))
```

The result is `NULL`, but why `A` + `NULL` + `B` will output `AB` instead of `AB`?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP asked us for the result of a sql query which could be answered by himself

Comment: Note ltrim(x) will return NULL if x is NULL.

Comment: @AlexK. but how `A` + `NULL` + `B` will output `AB` not `NULL`?

Comment: There is a difference between NULL and the empty string.

Comment: @YellowBedwetter, I see, ur right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASCII function produces the null result, not the TRIM function:

```
SELECT ASCII('')--NULL
SELECT ASCII(rtrim('    '))--NULL
SELECT rtrim('    ')--empty string
SELECT 'A' + ltrim('    ') + 'B'--'A' + empty string + 'B' = 'AB'
```

The data type of the concatenation result now depends on implicit conversions on which the constraints take priority:

```
SELECT CAST(sql_variant_property((SELECT 'A' + ltrim('    ') + 'B'),'BaseType') as varchar(20))
SELECT CAST(sql_variant_property((SELECT N'A' + ltrim('    ') + 'B'),'BaseType') as varchar(20))
SELECT CAST(sql_variant_property((SELECT 'A' + ltrim('    ') + N'B'),'BaseType') as varchar(20))
SELECT CAST(sql_variant_property((SELECT N'A' + ltrim('    ') + N'B'),'BaseType') as varchar(20))
```